# Flex Layout - What does "flex-basis: 1e-09px" mean?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

When using Angular Flex Layout I have noticed that it applied `flex: 0 1 1e-09px` to an element.

Was just wondering what the `1e-09px` means and if this is a valid value for this field or just an error.

Comment: General remark: it’s CSS [scientific notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number#valid_numbers), where `1e-9` is 10⁻⁹ (decimal separator shifted 9 places to the left) and `1e9` is 10⁹ (a 1 with 9 zeroes), so e.g. `4e1px` is `40px`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Github page](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/338):

> `1e-09px` is shorthand for `0.000000001px` and I believe it's a hack for
>   IE:
>
> [flex-layout/src/lib/flexbox/api/flex.spec.ts](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/bc0c90070a49dfccaa63300bba6c8fdf1a1d3879/src/lib/flexbox/api/flex.spec.ts#L68)
>
> `let hasFlex = _.hasStyle(dom, 'flex', '1 1 1e-09px') ||         // IE`

Answer (score 2):

It occurs when we declare just `fxFlex` on `div` like :

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
  //...
</div>
```

It can be fixed by using `fxFlex="100%"`

```
<div fxFlex="100%" fxLayout="row"> //<--- fxFlex has 100% value
  //...
</div>
```

hope it helps someone.